# Save existing DataGridView data to a new table in MS Access

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, save, load, create-table

I have an existing DataTable that binded to `DataGridView1`.
Loading table `jobentry`
with 3 fields `[name]`, `[quantity]` and `[cost]`
I have several comboboxes and textboxes for the dataentry to this gridview.

Now,
For each job, I want to save new table of information. (or load existing ones)

for example,
**`job # 1000`**,
I can have these 3 fields `[name]`, `[quantity]` and `[cost]` and it could have 1~5 rows of information. I want to be able to save/load this from MS Access 2010

so for different **`job#'s`**, I want to be able to load these saved datatable information. How can I save(or make it to a new table)?

I have 2 Categories created in MS Access 2010, I want to create new table into the category named `Job Database` and whenever I want to load existing ones, I want to find that table named "`jobdatabase"&job#`" and load it to `DataGridView1`.

I know the logic behind it, but I am not really familiar with VB.net codes (and proper ways to do it). Could you guide me what codes I need to be using?

Comment: you dont need (or want) a different table for each job,  You just need an identifier column in the `Job` table to store which rows belong to which job.   You might also want a Sequence column if the rows for Job `1000` are order specific

Comment: can I do what you said with vector data? Each job is going to have 3xn data (and that n could be 1~how ever many)

Comment: Thanks again Plutonix, you are helping me a lot.

Comment: `3xn` simply describes a relationship in the database.  It might be that there is a `Job` table which defines job-level stuff such as the name/ID/Type/Description etc; then a JobItem to store the job data details

Comment: Sorry, Plutonix, but could you expand your explanation if possible? I have a feeling that what you are describing would be what I am ultimately looking for, but things are not making sense in my head.

I know how to create relationships in access but wouldn't I have to create new tables each time I wanna create a new job entry?

Comment: No, this is not the place for a tutorial on database design or database theory. Your job table would store the data which defines a job (including 1000, 1001 or whatever identifier).  A new job would just be a new entry (row) the job detail would be related to it via FK.

Comment: Okay, thanks, Plutonix for help. I will look for a different place to learn database design. Thanks for the direction.